# Creating CSS circles connected by lines to middle main circle

Tags: html, css, css-position

[image: creating css circles connected by lines to middle main circle]

I need to create a page something like this. The blue circle is the main circle and green circles should place around the main circle. The green circles count is random (around 0 - 10). All green circles are connected to blue circle with a line.

I know to draw circle in CSS. I need to know,

1. How to place green circles around the blue circle
2. How to connect green circles to the blue circle

Is it possible to do with CSS. If not what is the way?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: You probably want to use canvas or SVG for this.  HTML+CSS is pretty limited for this sort of graph rendering.

Comment: So far I have created a main circle and I have no idea how to create other circles and how to place around main circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you will need is a `position: relative;` container with child elements positioned `absolute`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wFq6r/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wFq6r/59/)</kbd> (Using `transform`)

Explanation: What am doing here is using `position: relative;` on the parent element which is `.ball_wrap`, than am using `position: absolute;` for the child elements AS WELL AS the `:after` pseudo elements to connect the child elements with the parent. If you are not aware of the pseudo elements than take them as a virtual element, these elements do not exist literally in the DOM but they do render graphically. So am using `display: block;` as they are `inline` by default..along with `content: "";`... Rest, set them accordingly using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties.

```
.ball_wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 150px;
    width: 90px;
}

.green_ball {
    background: #00C762;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
}

.blue_ball {
    background: #2F9BC1;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 20px;
    left: -100px;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(2):after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    right: -50px;
    top: 50%;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 20px;
    right: -100px;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(3):after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    left: -52px;
    top: 50%;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(4) {
    right: 20px;
    bottom: -100px;
}

.ball_wrap div:nth-of-type(4):after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    top: -52px;
}
```

---

Also you might take a look at [these types of charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) using jQuery

Comment: Thanks, But in this I need to put custom values according to how many numbers of green circles.

Comment: @Sassi yes, you need to

Comment: But my problem is when I added this to site green circle count is varied to 1 to 10, may be more. I can't put hard coded values.

Comment: @Sassi than CSS and HTML only won't help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create the round shapes just with plain CSS:

**html:**

```
<div id="ball" class="border"> 
    <div class="blue ball"> </div>
</div>
<div id="ball1" class="border"> 
    <div class="green ball"> </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.border
{
    position: relative;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    background: #e7e9e9;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.ball
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 9%;    
    top: 9%;

    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;

    border-radius: 100px;
}

.blue
{
    background: #2f9bc1;
    border: 2px solid #266a8e;
}

.green
{
   background: #00c762; 
   border: 2px solid #00be58;
}

#ball
{
    top: 200px;   
    left: 300px;
}
```

Where you place each shape at the right position with `position: relative;` offset.

For the lines you could use [HTML 5 canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/):

**html:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" class="line"></canvas>
```

**javascript canvas:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(350, 150);
context.lineTo(50, 50);
context.stroke();
```

Where i use a `position: absolute;` for the line, so it doesn't push the shapes away and a z-index so it is beneath the shapes:

```
.line
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SXMnR/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sample html in using canvas.

--- html ---

```
<div style="border:solid thick #000">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

--- javascript ---

```
<script>
            var ctx;
            window.onload = function() {
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                if (!canvas || !canvas.getContext) {
                    return false;
                }
                canvas.width = 600;
                canvas.height = 600;
                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');           
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
                ctx.translate(300, 300);
                drawChildCircles(5);
                ctx.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);//center circle
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();                 
            }

            function drawChildCircles(n) {
                var ang_unit = Math.PI * 2 / n;
                ctx.save();
                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    ctx.rotate(ang_unit);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
                    ctx.lineTo(100,0);
                    ctx.arc(100, 0, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }
        </script>
```

However, I believe that the best way is to use svg with d3.js,
especially if you want to draw some data visualization or relation map.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8gf5/) using `svg` elements. SVG elements are very good for these kinda cases.

You'll get more info over [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp).

If you're trying to do some visualizations out of it. I'd suggest you to get along with [**d3**](http://d3js.org). A javascript library that used svg elements to create amazing visualization.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="container">
   <svg id="red">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="red-line">
        <line x1="130" y1="50" x2="300" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="blue">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="blue"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="blue-line">
        <line x1="130" y1="50" x2="260" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="green">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="green-line">
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="70" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,255);stroke-width:2"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="yellow">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="yellow"/>
    </svg>
```

**CSS :**

```
    #container {
      position: relative;
      margin: 150px 0 0 250px;
    }
    #container svg {
      position: absolute;
    }
    #blue {
      top: -150px;
    }
    #green {
      left: -200px;
    }
    #yellow {
      left: 200px;
    }
    #blue-line {
      margin-left: -200px;
    }
    #green-line {
      margin-top: -60px;
    }
```