# Creating CSS circles connected by lines to one main circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, web

[circle example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znilS.png)

I need to create a page something like figure shown.

The main circle which is green has to been connect to the 2 sub circle with line using css and html..kindly provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.left-box,
.right-box {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-box {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.right-box .circle + .circle {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ed1c24;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  width: 70px;
}

.big-circle {
  background: #52883b;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.purple {
  background: #ec008c;
}

.circle .circle-content {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.circle.one:before,
.circle.two:before {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
  background: #000;
  width: 74px;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
}

.circle.two:before {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="left-box">
  <div class="big-circle circle">
    <div class="circle-content">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-box">
  <div class="circle one">
    <div class="circle-content">1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle purple two">
    <div class="circle-content">1.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for making circle in web page use `border-radius:50%;` for connecting use the appropriate margins as your page needed. And please next time provide the code for getting better help.

Answer (score 0):

One of similar post i found

[Creating CSS circles connected by lines to middle main circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042587/creating-css-circles-connected-by-lines-to-middle-main-circle)

in this they are connecting for one circle multiple circles as been connected but i required as per the image