# How to build a radial converging diagram?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

This is the design for what I want to achieve:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bkzy.png)

Basically, I want to have a middle bubble that represents Home of the App. Now we have a bigger imaginary bubble(cercle) and on his circumference I want to have a given number of circles(anywhere from 2 to 10). All these cercles will be connected with an arrow to the Home bubble.

How can I achieve this with html,css and js? I've searched a lot for this but can't find any example for now. Another example is here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqp25.png)

Thank you!

I use Angular in my application and no libraries for now.

I've tried this solution from here: [Creating CSS circles connected by lines to middle main circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042587/creating-css-circles-connected-by-lines-to-middle-main-circle) but when it comes to connecting the lines I haven't managed to get it done. For my angular app I've created a separate component for cercle and I've passed the top and left position as Inputs. But I don't think that's a good solution cause I will need to control also the lines that will connect to the Home bubble and change the color of it based on some properties that every individual cercle will have.

Answer (score 0):

In pure HTML/CSS you can do this by using the transform: rotate function.

Have a series of rectangular divs (1-5 in this case) with a background line created down the center using linear-gradient. Position each at the center of the container with top 0 and rotate them about their bottom center.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    --height: 100vmin;
    --half-height: calc(var(--height) / 2);
    --num: 5;
    height: var(--height);
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(1) {
    --n: 1;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(2) {
    --n: 2;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(3) {
    --n: 3;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(4) {
    --n: 4;
  }
  
  .container>div:nth-child(5) {
    --n: 5;
  }
  
  .container>div {
    height: var(--half-height);
    --w: 70px;
    width: var(--w);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(calc((var(--n) - 1) * 360deg / 5));
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    left: calc(var(--half-height) - ( var(--w) / 2));
  }
  
  .container>div>div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: pink;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I integrate another cercle inside those 5 cercles?

Comment: Do you mean the single circle in the center of the container? That's just another div as a child of the container. I am not seeing what the problem is.